# I want to drop a platform after I land on it

Tags: unreal-4

I want to disable z-axis translation lock 2 seconds after my player hits the object in question. I am using Unreal 4. Been slamming my head against it for a week and a half, please save this newb.

I just noticed this is the iteration where I enabled gravity instead of disabling z lock... the intended result is be the same for both of these
[image: this is what i have so far]

UPDATE

now the thing drops but it doesnt wait for the timer

[image]

UPDATE! I DID IT!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried!

Comment: [It's fine to answer your own question, by the way.](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) Could you write up your final solution?

Answer (score 1):

Final solution

turns out I was using a timer and not a timeline.. timers are like stopwatches and count up, timelines are like egg timers and count down

[image]